# django set a cusotme page number in paginate_queryset

Tags: django, django-views

I want to write a code that find the user page number and return that page:
this is the code that find the page_number:

```
class UserScoreBoard(GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-xp_balance')
    serializer_class = UserSerializerReadOnly

    @action(url_path='user-page', methods=['get'], detail=False, url_name='user-page')
    def get_user_page(self, request):
        page_size = int(request.query_params.get('page_size')) if request.query_params.get('page_size') else \
            self.pagination_class.page_size
        user_page = User.objects.filter(xp_balance__lt=request.user.xp_balance).count() // page_size + 1
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return serializer
```

which the user_page is the page that contains the user. how can i set the user_page in this code?